# Unwanted gap between div content and border on the right side

Tags: html, css

I was working on a toolbar and I ran into this issue where when I created a border around the outside of the toolbox there is a gap between the content of the toolbar and the actual toolbar border. I have tried making the padding and margin 0.

```css
#tool-panel {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 370px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.elem {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool-panel">
  <div id="ruler" class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

This image shows the problem:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for converting it to a demo I didn't know you could do that. Yes I do still see it, if you look on the right side of the box there's a gap between the line separators and the toolbar's border. https://imgur.com/TNxmdwY

Comment: Is your browser zoomed? I only see that when I change scaling. It's probably a pixel rounding error.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the browser. I tested it locally, it renders normally: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp8iE.png). I got this image by magnifying the browser screen 300%.

Comment: @HcHc what browser are you running?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: @HcHc Weird, so am I and I don't see the gap. Do you see the gap when running a snippet or only locally?

Comment: @HcHc This gap appears when the browser screen is enlarged 125% and %175: [test-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqI7a.png)

Comment: Thanks I think you solved it

Answer (score 0):

There is no `border-collapse` here, like there is for `<table>`s. So the problem is caused because there isn't a true connection between the inner border (on the children) and the outer border on the parent.

---

One alternative you could use, is to remove the border from the parent (`#tool-panel`) and instead only use the one on the children (as you're already using that anyway):

```
.elem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.elem:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Another alternative (in certain conditions) could be to remove the border from the child (`.elem`), keep the border on the parent (`#tool-panel`), and:

```
#tool-panel {
  background-color: black;
}
.elem {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.elem:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And just for good measure, a third approach could be to set:

```
.elem {
  margin: 0 -1px 0 -1px;
}
```